# xetex: setting a font only for the text

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am using

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
```

to change the "text" font in my latex document. However this has messed up some math equations and things like

```
\mathbf{E} \exp \sin \cos
```

are also displayed using the font for the text which makes it look ugly and inconsistent with the rest of equation.

Is there a way to fix this so that the above specified font is only used for text and not anywhere in the equations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` instead of `xltxtra` (assuming that you have a recent fontspec).

Comment: I have to use `xltxtra` since Ubuntu is a ttf font

Comment: @user6530 `xltxtra` loads `fontspec`, and unless you need some of the specific functions it offers, (mainly the XeTeX logos) it is no longer needed. `fontspec` is the main package for using fonts of any sort with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @user6530: Why do you reject my suggestion without trying it?

Comment: can you elaborate on `fontspec`. if I put `\usepackage[no-math]{Ubunut}` then the error message says `ubuntu.sty not found`. so what exactly I should do?

Comment: Well I wrote `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` not `\usepackage[no-math]{Ubunut}`. Beside this: fontspec has a documentation.

Comment: If you are not willing to search and peruse a documentation of a package: Don't use latex. It is not the right system for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to load the `mathspec` package before `xltxtra` (or `fontspec`)

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{xltxltra}
```

Optionally, you can define then a specific math font.